# Change to connection string in web.config on server is not going into effect after some time

Tags: asp.net, oracle, iis

We have recently reset the service account password and hence changed the connection string password in the `web.config` file (API) on the UAT servers. After replacing the new password, the API works for some time, but then the database account gets locked and it throws this exception:

```
"Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException": [   {
  "DataSource": "",
  "Message": "ORA-28000: the account is locked",
  "Number": 28000,
  "Procedure": "",
  "Source": "Oracle Data Provider for .NET",
  "ArrayBindIndex": -1
```

}]

When I checked the application windows log it shows the below error in a regular intervals

[image]

Is there any other way to update the `web.config`? Or is the old password is still cached somewhere?

Comment: Have you recycled the IIS app pool after the config change?

Comment: no its already set to fixed interval 1740 minutes. Is there a chance that any other service is running which I am not aware which still takes the old password ? any method to identify such services. services which I know I already stopped.

Comment: The web.config file is read by the application when the IIS server starts, so any values modified in web.config will require a restart of the IIS server to load them into memory. You can modify the dynamic connection string, but the application will still run on the previous connection string. So IIS needs to be restarted to load the new connection string.

Comment: @YurongDai you meant IISRESET ?

Comment: one strange thing - even I have stopped the WebApi in the application pool still application windows log shows the same error

Comment: I would restart the web server when this is done. Don't have to reboot the server,  but from the iis administration you can re start the web site but better is to restart the web server from the  iis administrator